# Docker save can't export ~50GB image because no space, although I have 150GB free

Tags: docker

I am simply trying to export a Docker image that I have so that I can push it to another system; however, I cannot even save it because of no space:

```
$ docker save mycustomimage:latest -o nessus.tar
Error response from daemon: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-export-255300778/f2881cc25962de53a9f4efdbf759e88c86bd183abf773477ebbd5ddebc229ae8/layer.tar: no space left on device
```

However, if I run `df -h`, I can confirm that I have over 150GB of free space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity     iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   466Gi  275Gi  182Gi    61%     1290334 9223372036853485473    0%   /
devfs          374Ki  374Ki    0Bi   100%        1296                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   466Gi  8.0Gi  182Gi     5%           8 9223372036854775799    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%           0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%           0                   0  100%   /home
drivefs        466Gi  292Gi  173Gi    63% 18446744069414640546          4294967295 32808793364899312%   /Volumes/GoogleDrive
```

here's a list of the images:

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mycustomimage/kali      latest              a1f226987b86        12 hours ago        33GB
mycustomimage/kali      <none>              ac3292dcbd65        4 months ago        25.1GB
mycustomimage/kali      <none>              8a628403a803        6 months ago        12GB
```

I am not even sure if all of these images are 33GB combined, or 33GB is just the file size of the last image. It's just a simple Kali Linux docker with one custom tool on it that is about 5GB in space. I'm pretty sure that, if this image is 70GB large, then it's larger than my VM which has even more stuff installed.

Comment: How did the image get so big?  You aren’t using `docker commit`, are you?  (IME managing Docker images much above 1 GB becomes troublesome in various ways, this among them.)

Comment: Yeah -- once I made changes to the docker image, I ran docker commit. I was attempting to commit the changes to the current docker image instead of create a new image. Is it suggested to let docker build the images each time instead of this?

Comment: If you take an image, add or modify a 5 GB file in it, and `docker commit`, the new image will be the size of the old image plus 5 GB.  Always.

Comment: @DavidMaze Does this mean i can delete the old image, or do the new ones depend on the old ones? Any suggestions for saving changes without creating a new image? I thought I was doing this until I reviewed this. still relatively new here so thanks for the help.

Comment: Using `docker commit` isn’t usually a best practice.  You’re better off writing a Dockerfile that can generate your image, reproducibly, from a clean slate, and running `docker build` (often in an automation pipeline) to generate the image.  For the case you’re describing, you can `docker push` the built image to a repository and then `docker pull` it on the other host.

Comment: You can delete the old images but that won’t free up any space.  Debug-level commands like `docker images -a` will still show them hanging around as base layers of your final image.

Comment: @DavidMaze I gotcha. Thanks for the suggestion. Since this isn't hosted on a repository, I was going to use `docker save` to export it into a file and transfer it to another system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `df -h` output corresponds with the output that I would expect to see *on a mac*, which means your linux containers are not running on the system where `df -h` was run.

If you are running the Docker Desktop for mac, then your docker daemon is running inside a hyperkit virtual machine that the whale icon Docker.app application manages in the background. This virtual machine includes a virtual disk with a finite size. The smallest configurable disk size for this disk image is 16GB. To see how much space your whale icon docker desktop managed virtual machine has, click on the whale icon, and choose "Preferences". Under the "Disk" tab, you will see how big the disk is, and how much space it is taking up (due to compression).

When the `docker save` command is run, the daemon will create a .tar at the location referenced in your error output, `/var/lib/docker/tmp/...`. Since your virtual machine's disk does not have enough space for that temporary .tar file, you get a disk out of space error.

To see the true amount of space available to the VM, run the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /var/lib/docker/tmp:/r alpine df -h /r
```

It is possible to increase the amount of space your disk image has available to it, but keep in mind that will take up real space on your hard drive even once the large files are deleted from the filesystem on the disk image.

tldr; you are running docker in a virtual machine that has less space available to it than your host machine shows as available.

Answer (score 1):

I pruned some images and containers and after that it worked.

```
docker image prune
```

and

```
docker container prune
```

https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/